# Set not required property ASP.NET Core SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Some of the string properties in the class do not have a `[Required]` attribute, and when migrating it to SQL Server, it adds a `NOT NULL` property. I have revised the code so much but didn't reach any solution yet.

```
   public class Stores
   {
        [Key]
        public int StoreID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Store Name")]
        public string StoreName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Store Bio")]
        public string Bio { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Store Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

This is the SQL code generated

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stores] 
(
    [StoreID]                 INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StoreName]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Bio]                     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Description]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [BrandsBrandID]           INT            NULL,
    [CategoriesCategoryID]    INT            NULL,
    [CollectionsCollectionID] INT            NULL,
    [ProductsProductID]       INT            NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Stores] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StoreID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stores_Brands_BrandsBrandID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BrandsBrandID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stores_Categories_CategoriesCategoryID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CategoriesCategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stores_Collections_CollectionsCollectionID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CollectionsCollectionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Collections] ([CollectionID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stores_Products_ProductsProductID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProductsProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID])
);
```

[This is the sql code generated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTcy1.png)

Comment: What is generating the SQL?  If EF use OnModelCreating to override the [Required] attribute.  But it's a better practice to use Null instead of empty strings in both .NET and the database.

Comment: Can you share your DBcontext code and the code generated by migration ?You also can check it out.  Or you can use a Stores class to generate the database to see whether the one that not add required is NULL or NOT NULL in SQL-Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems totally correct. So try this one: Clear SQL cache.

- Select *Edit* > *IntelliSense* > *Refresh Local Cache*

or

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Nullable from the project file.

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Remove the above line.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 8 [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) was introduced, this mean that to allow null for a `string` property (note that `String` is a reference type) you must add `?` to the definition.

Change your code in the following way and EF will correctly derive a nullable column:

```cs
public string? Bio { get; set; } = null;
```